# Dirac Comb Times Step Function

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-restriction

Can someone explain me what is the effect of the Heaviside step function $\Theta(t)$ on a Dirac Comb (Fourier series)?

> $$ \left[\,\,\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_{n}\,\delta\left(t - nT_{0}\right) \right]\Theta(t) = ?$$

Comment: What is $\displaystyle{\large\delta_{-1}\left(t\right)}$ ?.

Comment: Is the Heaviside function. I was thinking to use the expression of the Heaviside function as $ \delta_{-1}(t)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} sng(t)$. I am expecting a truncate Dirac Comb summation, but I don't know how to proceed

Comment: A current notation is $\large\Theta\left(t\right)$. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is dangerous to try to truncate a Dirac comb so "sharply" as by multiplication by a translate of Heaviside. It is safe only when the jump in the translate of Heaviside is strictly between the spikes of the comb.

(It is dangerous to think that "declaring" the value of Heaviside at $0$ to be $1/2$ repairs anything or makes it safe.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $T_0>0$ then drop all the -ve n from the summation.
Care needed with n=0, I think the Heaviside(t=0) is equal 1/2 in which case you will have a term $c_0 /2$. +n remains unchanged.

Comment: Yes in fact I was thinking something like $ \frac{c_{0}}{2}+\sum_{n=1} ^{+\infty}c_{n}\delta(t-nT_{0})$ but this is by intuition: I mean, if I multiply the summation for $ \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}sng(t)$ I don't manage to prove that this is the result